# Why YARN resource manager is failing?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

YARN Resource Manager is failing showing the following error in logs:

```
2019-09-27 11:23:36,473 ERROR webapp.Dispatcher (Dispatcher.java:service(171)) - error handling URI: /cluster
```

YARN is installed in a HDP cluster version 3.0.1.

Comment: I hope you get more logs than just that

Comment: Yes, the same log continuously. This is the first part of the trace.

Comment: @Shadowtrooper Did you find any solution?